# Removing nVidia driver from Fedora causes references to missing file nvidia-tls

Tags: linux, fedora, xorg, nvidia-graphics-card, fedora-22

I had installed the nVidia driver from rpmfusion-nonfree and it has been working fine for a long time(From fedora 18 I think).

But now I wanted to switch to the opensource driver, so I removed the nvidia driver(dnf erase akmod-nvidia*) and then things started to get weird.

Because with the driver removed kde5, still tries to reference the nvidia-tls*.so files(And som other opengl nvidia files I can't remember the name of) which was part of the nvidia driver. The fires are thus removed so loading of kde5 fails.

I can start the gui in failsafe mode, but if I try to start a browser such as firefox og chrome, they also both complain about missing nvidia*so files.

I even tried to remove my nVidia graphics card from my computer, and use the buildin ivy-bridge graphics for my motherboard. But even when doing that, X11 still complains about missing nvidia-tls.so file despite my computer not having any nVidia hardware at that point.

So it's like X11/Kde want to use the nvidia driver even after its been uninstalled and the hardware removed. Anyone who got a clue about what's wrong and how to solve it?

------------------------ EDIT ----------------------------------

One thing I remember now is that i originally(Before I installed the driver from rpmfusion-unfree) tried to install the nvidia driver downloaded from nvidia (http://www.nvidia.com/object/unix.html) but I newer got it to work with a compiled kernel so I have up and ran the uninstaller.

It might something gone wrong from that install, which messes up my system.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things to check here:

1. You state you removed the akmod-nvidia RPM. Did you also remove the generated kmod-nvidia RPM associated with your running kernel?
2. Does /etc/X11/xorg.conf or a file in /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d exist which defines the Driver as being nvidia? xorg.conf should be removed when the kmod-nvidia RPM is removed but otherwise may still be present.
3. Did you regenerate the initramfs using dracut after verifying that kmod-nvidia has been removed? One action of installing the nvidia driver is to blacklist the noveau driver at boot through the initramfs.

If you investigate and attend to the above you should resolve your problem.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: 1:Yes I removed the kmod and kmod-nvidia-304xx package. 
2:Not sure. (I had to reinstall the nvidia graphics card, and reinstall the akmod-nvidia driver to get a working system.). So those files obviously mentions nvidia now, but I am pretty sure they did not do that before.
3: Not explicit, but the package  should do that for me, right? I have never invoked dracut explicit.  

But  the problem was there even when the nvidia graphics card was removed, and I used the intel driver.